# How to cache views in django

Tags: python, django

I am currently using django and I'm attempting to cache my view like so

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def index(request):
   # This method takes time to run, which is why I need to cache this view
   a_method_that_preforms_heavy_db_transactions()

   context_dict={'Models': Model.objects.all()} 
   return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context_dict)
```

I have `a_method_that_preforms_heavy_db_transactions()` In just to test the loading time to see if it cached the view but the loading time time doesn't change when its supposed to be "cached" and I'm unsure why this is my settings.py

```
 CACHES = {
    'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': 'My_computers_ip_address:11211',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add a `caching service`, e.g Memcached

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211/A_ROUTE_WITH_A_HEAVY_TRANSACTION',
    }
}
```

You'll find everything you need here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/

Comment: i set it up 'CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '192.168.1.6:11211',
    }
}

Comment: Nice. Make sure you read the link I provided...It has vital steps to how you get it up and running. `note` that the LOCATION in my example is pointing to a random IP, your `IP` may be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost:300`, up to you to find out! @the1.7gpaprogrammer

Comment: I had made that edit in my code before I first asked the question and its still not working

Comment: You actually have to start a memcached server instance - https://memcached.org/ | Check this: https://djangosteps.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/setup-memcache-for-django-in-a-development-environment/

Answer (score 1):

Have you [set caching up](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/)? You need to define `CACHES` in your `settings.py` file. You can use memcached, Redis, your database or a file system. The simplest setup is with local memory as it doesn't require any external services:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```